# object is passed as an argument , why cant we declare it inside the class instead

Tags: java

The problem with this code is that whenever i run this it shows the

compilation error-

"cannot find symbol:constructor mywindowadapter(frame1)

location:class mywindowadapter
               mywindowadapter mwa=new mywindowadapter()"

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
/*<applet code=frame2 width=500 height=500>
</applet>*/
class frame2 extends Frame
{
    frame2(String title)
    {
        super(title);
        mywindowadapter mwa=new mywindowadapter();
        addWindowListener(mwa);     
    }
    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
        frame1 f=new frame1("my frame");
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(200,100);

     }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
     {
    g.drawString("hello frame",60,70);
     }
}
class mywindowadapter extends WindowAdapter
{

    mywindowadapter()
    {
        frame2 f=new frame2();  
    }
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
    {
        f.setVisible(false);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

The code below is the rectified version of the above code. i am not able to understand the error generated in the previous code. please help!!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
/*<applet code=frame1 width=500 height=500>
</applet>*/
class frame1 extends Frame
 {
    frame1(String title)
    {
        super(title);
        mywindowadapter mwa=new mywindowadapter(this);
        addWindowListener(mwa);     
    }
    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
        frame1 f=new frame1("my frame");
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(200,100);

    }
   public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawString("hello frame",60,70);
    }
}
class mywindowadapter extends WindowAdapter
{
    frame1 f;
    mywindowadapter(frame1 f)
    {
        this.f=f;   
    }
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
    {
        f.setVisible(false);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well theres a bunch of syntax errors in your code, is this just a copy past problem? can you elaborate on " why cant we declare object simply in the class below instead of passing it as an argument." give me the exact code with the error.

Comment: Is the code that shows what you're trying to do (and that generates the errors) posted above?  If so, where?  Also, what errors?  There are indeed several syntax errors in the code you pasted.

Answer (score 0):

Because in the constructor of the `frame1` you are trying to create an adapter instance that utilize the [Adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) and delegates processing event to the adaptee `frame1` which reference you pass as an argument. This adapter is used by the listener which you add to the listeners list of the `frame1`.